# Circle isn't in the shape of a circle

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality

Printer doesn't print perfect circles while calicat is perfect and top layers look weird on Ender 3 Pro:

[image: top layers look weird]

[image: circle isn't in the shape of a circle while calicat was perfect]

I used Cura and an Ender 3 Pro, eSun PLA+, print at 210 °C.

Comment: Are the belts tight?

Answer (score 1):

Try printing a 20mm reference cube and verify the dimensions.  Also calibrate your extruder - it looks "fat" to me like there's just too much plastic.

I print the same filament at the same temperature, on an ender3 v2 so you're in the right area for temperatures.